# Insert first item in ul to last

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked into how you can append the first item in an ul to the last using `$("#slideShow1 ul li:first").appendTo('#slideshow1 ul');` I want to add some additional effects to the slideshow but I've found out even moving li items won't work.

Here's the html and the demo on http://jsfiddle.net/7L4b8cbd/4/

```
<div id="slideShowContainer">
    <div id="slideShow">

        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/11/rotating-slideshow-jquery-css3/img/photos/1.jpg" width="100%" alt="Fish" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/11/rotating-slideshow-jquery-css3/img/photos/2.jpg" width="100%" alt="Ancient" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/11/rotating-slideshow-jquery-css3/img/photos/3.jpg" width="100%" alt="Industry" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/11/rotating-slideshow-jquery-css3/img/photos/4.jpg" width="100%" alt="Rain" /></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <a id="previousLink" href="#">&raquo;</a>
    <a id="nextLink" href="#">&laquo;</a>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#slideShow ul li:first").appendTo('#slideshow ul');
$("#slideShow ul li:first").appendTo('#slideshow ul');
$("#slideShow ul li:first").appendTo('#slideshow ul');
```

EDIT:
I'm now referrencing to the right ul but it's still now working.

Comment: `slideShow` != `slideShow1` != `slideshow1`

Comment: @epascarello under external libraries it is there

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8mkkysma/1/

Comment: In your html slideShow and in javascript selector you have used slideShow1. I found the extra "1". Though your requirement is till not clear to me.

Comment: You can look at the edited version I want the first picture in the ul to be pushed to the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what how your three jQuery statements work but the following code should do the job :

```
var x = $("#slideShow ul li:first");
$("#slideShow ul li:first").remove();
$('#slideShow ul').append(x);
```

This will move the first element to the last. Repeat it as many times as required.

Checkout - http://jsfiddle.net/7L4b8cbd/5/

Answer (score 0):

This ID in the HTML was `slideShow` and your selectors were `slideshow1` and `slideShow1`, none of which match.

```
<div id="slideShowContainer">
    <div id="slideShow1">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#slideShow1 ul li:first").appendTo('#slideShow1 ul');
$("#slideShow1 ul li:first").appendTo('#slideShow1 ul');
$("#slideShow1 ul li:first").appendTo('#slideShow1 ul');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7L4b8cbd/3/